# Use the new version of Webstorm

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu

I was using `Webstorm 2016.1` version.

Today I download `Webstorm 2017.1` version from the offical website.

After downloading I extract the `tar.gz`. And in terminal, I go to the extracted `folder/bin` and execute `./webstorm.sh`.

When I terminate the `./webstorm.sh` in terminal, webstorm is closed. Also when I search Webstorm in the applications list, I get the older version. How should I use new version of `Webstorm` rather than opening it via `./webstorm.sh` command. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can run the app from the terminal as long as you add an ampersand at the end of your command. This will prevent webstorm from closing from the terminal.

Or, option two and the most practical is to create a .desktop file which will create a launch icon in the Slingshot menu.

Here is an example file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=Webstorm 
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/user/Documents/webstorm.sh <--- enter the full path to you app
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/icon.png <-- optional but nice to have
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Name the file whatever with a .desktop extension and place it in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: To get rid of the old version of WebStorm, look in the directory listed above (and also /usr/local) to find the .desktop file for the old version of WebStorm. Delete the file and the old version of WebStorm. See also: https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#the-desktop-file

Comment: Good call. Also rather than delete the file, he could just edit it with the updated path to the new version.

Comment: This happened to me when I extracted the webstorm.tar.gz installer to `/tmp`. I extracted the files to a persistant folder `~/Applications/Webstorm` and the desktop file and app worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new [Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/) to keep your Jetbrains IDEs up-to-date